# Custom installation in Wix Patch

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

In the wix major upgrade, I have a set of features and the end user has the option to install either typical, custom or complete features.

In case of wix patch release, is it possible to give the user the same option of typical, custom or complete installation type.

Else during the deployment can wix patch detect which features to be deployed based on the installation done in a system. i.e if a system is installed with typical installation then the wix patch update only those components that belong to typical installation. and if a system has a custom installation with only feature X then the patch update should update only those components that belong to feature X.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Although wix is a programming tool (and hence this question is not off topic), you might have more look posting this on http://superuser.com

Comment: @GHC - I have no idea where you came up with that. The WiX tag doesn't even exist on SuperUser.  It exists here with 3678 questions.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I'm still finding my way around reviewing questions; the question seemed not to be to do with a programming problem but more about installing software.  Reading more about WiX it now makes perfect sense.  I'll be more thorough in future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to let the user select the features again.  That would be a MajorUpgrade with the msidbUpgradeAttributesMigrateFeatures attribute and showing the Custom Setup dialog.

In a Minor Upgrade / Patch the original feature installation states are remembered.  If you need something wierd like an EXE/DLL is installed  but during the patch uninstalled, you'd need to look at the concept of "puncturing" components using the msidbComponentAttributesTransitive attribute.